# Derive property from continuity - is this proof valid?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity

Prove that if $f:R^+ \rightarrow R^+$ is continuous on the positive reals and is decreasing, then for all $a$ there exists an $\eta > 0$ such that $(a-\eta)f(a-\eta) > \frac{1}{2}a*f(a)$.

EDIT - The proof in the error was identified, and I can see how it can be easily proved just by using the fact that it is decreasing. However, is it possible to prove this statement just using the continuity condition?

Comment: There is a mistake in your "Because $f$ is decreasing" sentence, the inequality involving $f(x)$ is incorrect.

Comment: EDIT - I see the error

Comment: It seems to me that it is possible to prove this without continuity - just use the decreasing property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint on how to prove it: Ignore continuity. You have the decreasing property, so you know that for $0<\eta<a$, you have that
$$f(a-\eta)>f(a).$$

You want to get $\frac a 2$ on the right, and you could certainly do that if you multiplied everything by $\frac a 2$, so how can you tweak this to end up with $\frac a 2$ on the right and $(a-\eta)$ on the left? (Hint: restrict your choice of $\eta$ further.)

You can also completely ignore the decreasing property. The fact that this might be possible should be intuitively signaled by the fact that $\lim_{\eta \to 0}(a-\eta)f(a-\eta) = af(a)>\frac 1 2 a f(a)$ if $f$ is continuous at $a$. We should turn this visual picture into a proof as follows:

Since $f$ is continuous, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $|(a-\eta)-a|=|\eta|<\delta$ implies $|(a-\eta)f(a-\eta)-af(a)|<\frac 1 2 a f(a)$. Therefore
$$-\frac 1 2 a f(a) < (a-\eta)f(a-\eta)-af(a) < \frac 1 2 a f(a)$$
but we don't really care about the right side, because adding $af(a)$ to the left and the middle yields
$$\frac 1 2 a f(a)<(a-\eta)f(a-\eta).$$
Literally having a visual picture to look at helps tremendously. This shows that not only is there at least one $\eta$ that works, but a whole interval of them.

Comment: I understand this proof clearly, but is it possible to prove the statement without the fact that it is decreasing?

Comment: It is possible, I will post a proof now.